# Finding the vertices of an object with angles (polygon)

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems

This is a really simple trig problem, but my brain is stuck on it. I'm designing an object in OpenSCAD (3D Drafting), and in order to 'draw' the object, I need to specify a set of points [x,y]. Together, the points makes a closed polygon. Ex: Square is represented by [0,0],[10,0],[10,10],[0,10]

I'm fine with 90 degree corners, but when my object has angles, I don't know how to specify the correct coordinates, and my objects come out skewed. **Basically, given a curved object, how do I determine a set of coordinates?**

Example: Trying to determine the x-coordinates for an angled object:

[image: Finding x-coordinates given an angled object]

How would I find those two question mark coordinates?

Here is my current attempt, with 'eyeing' the coordinates:
[image: Red lines showing desired]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have a line that goes through $(0,0) and $(110, 30)

$110 y = 30 x$
or
$3 x - 11y = 0$
now you need a line that is parallel and 5 units away

$3 x - 11y + d=0$

$d = \sqrt{3^2 + 11^2}\cdot 5$

$3 x - 11y + 5\sqrt {130} = 0$

This line intersect the line y = 5

$x = \frac {55-5\sqrt {130}}3$

$(\frac {55 - 5\sqrt {130}}3, 5)$ is one of your missing coordinates.

The other coordinate:

the line perpendicular to 
$3x - 11 y = 0$
through the point $(110,30)$

$11(x-110) + 3(y-30) = 0\\
11x +3y - 1300=0$
intersects
$3 x - 11y + 5\sqrt {130} = 0$

$33x +9y - 3900=0\\
33x -121y +55\sqrt{130}=0\\
130 y = 3900 + 55\sqrt {130}\\
y = 30 + 55\frac{\sqrt {130}}{130}\\
x = 110 - 15\frac{\sqrt {130}}{130}$

$(110 - 15\frac{\sqrt {130}}{130},30 + 55\frac{\sqrt {130}}{130})$

Which you might notice is $(110,30) + \frac {5}{\sqrt{3^2+11^2}} (-3,11)$

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But calculating those numbers gives me: [108.69, 34.82] and [14.53, 5]. This seems off: (55−130√3,5) = (14.53, 5) , which can't be correct because it is the inner crook of the corner, meaning it should be closer to x=100 . Here are the points, and a screenshot of output: polygon(points = [[0,0],[100,0],[110,30],[108.69,34.82],[14.53,5],[0,5]]); http://imgur.com/a/vTyMN

Comment: That would be because I dropped a 5 in last step.